# How to setup SSL for DigitalOcean droplet

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, openlitespeed

How do I setup SSL for DigitalOcean droplet running OpenLiteSpeed NodeJS? Is there any command that I can run to make this possible? Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

**Auto setup:**

An interactive script that runs will first prompt you for your domain or subdomain.

You can press CTRL+C and continue to SSH. The prompt will open again the next time you log in, and will continue to do so until you finish the whole setup.

```
Please input a valid domain:
Please verify it is correct. [y/N]
```

*Enter the root domain only, then the system will add both the root domain and the www domain for you.*

You can also automatically apply Let's Encrypt SSL if your domain is pointed to this server already. Enter `y` and your email address to finish the process.

```
Do you wish to issue a Let's encrypt certificate for this domain? [y/N]
Please enter your E-mail:
Please verify it is correct: [y/N]
```

Once finished, you should see **Certificate has been successfully installed...**

```
Do you wish to force the HTTPS rewrite rule for this domain? [y/N]
```

Once finished, force HTTPS rules will be applied

```
Do you wish to update the system which includes the webserver? [Y/n]
```

This script will automatically go away after your domain has been added.

**Manually setup:**

1. Navigate to OpenLiteSpeed Web Server WebAdmin > Listeners, and add Your Domain to HTTP/HTTPS.
2. Once the DNS records are set up, you can generate the SSL certificate. Be sure to substitute the correct domain name in the following command:

```
certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/html/ -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

3. Navigate to OpenLiteSpeed Web Server WebAdmin > Listeners > SSL, and edit the following three items:

   - Private Key File = `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem`
   - Certificate File = `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem`
   - Chained Certificate = `Yes`
4. Save and perform a Graceful Restart.

Refer https://docs.litespeedtech.com/cloud/images/nodejs/#optional-setup

Comment: Thank you. Yes I did try that, but still error occurs.

Comment: Hi @RobertBautista, please send your issue to support@litespeedtech.com, I will help you from there more quickly. Please also share the steps you did and what's the output.